# Closing slider if same id is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I've been messing around with this for a bit and can't figure out why this isn't closing the div. I have a div (id="sideslider") that slides up from the bottom of the page when one of five images is clicked. If a user clicks the same image, I want it to close. It would also be a plus if it closed and reopened if a different image is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sidefooter").click(function(event) {
        id = event.target.id;
        console.log(oldid);
        console.log(id);
        $("#sideslider").load("sidefooter.php #" + id)
        var oldid = "";
        if (id !== oldid) {
            $('#sideslider').stop(true).animate({ 'margin-bottom': 0, 'opacity': '1' }, { queue: false, duration: 300 });
        oldid = id;
        }
        else if(id == oldid){
                $('#sideslider').stop(true).animate({ 'margin-bottom': -70, 'opacity': '0' }, { queue: false, duration: 300 });
           oldid = id;
        }

    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle that brings up the div, I need a way to get it back down.

http://jsfiddle.net/Gn8Dk/

Comment: It seems way too complicated, and from first looks it seems it could be done with just a few lines of code, but you should set up a fiddle to make it easier for us to test it.

Comment: I've added a fiddle and updated my code to my most recent iteration. I'll try some of the proposed solutions after dinner :) Thanks all!

Comment: @Justin I edited my answer according to the changes in the question. Have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must provide the mark up and as @adeneo commented, provide a fiddle to give a solution. Here is how I've interpreted your requirements (note I am just using toggle to slide the div back and forth). Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UT2R8/1/

**Edited After further info in question**

For your info, first part of your requirement would work with a minor change to your provided script. According to your code, on every click your oldid is set to " ". So you will need to move that outside the click scope. With that change your code should work partially. Here is the fiddle for the complete solution. http://jsfiddle.net/pCEDw/4/

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var oldid = "";
    $("#sidefooter").click(function(event) {
        id = event.target.id;

        console.log(oldid);
        console.log(id);
        $("#sideslider").load("sidefooter.php #" + id)

        if (id != oldid && oldid != "") {                
            $('#sideslider').stop(true).animate({ 'margin-bottom': -70, 'opacity': '0' },300).delay(300).queue(function() { $(this).stop(true).animate({ 'margin-bottom': 0, 'opacity': '1' }, 300);
                                                                                                                          $("#sideslider").html('Content yay. you clicked - ' + id);
                                                                                                                          });         
        oldid = id;
        }
        else if (id != oldid) { $('#sideslider').stop(true).animate({ 'margin-bottom': 0, 'opacity': '1' }, { queue: false, duration: 300 }); $("#sideslider").html('Content yay. you clicked - ' + id);  oldid = id;
        }           
        else if(id == oldid){                    
                $('#sideslider').stop(true).animate({ 'margin-bottom': -70, 'opacity': '0' }, { queue: false, duration: 300 });
           oldid = "";
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: This did it! Thanks Prashanth, I see where I was going wrong. Still have a lot to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var last = false;
$("img").click(function () {
  if ($('#sideslider').css('margin-bottom') == 0) {
      if (last != false && $(this) != last) {
          $('#sideslider').stop(true).animate({ 'margin-bottom': -70, 'opacity': '0' }, { queue: false, duration: 300 }).animate({ 'margin-bottom': 0, 'opacity': '1' }, { queue: false, duration: 300 });
      } else {
          $('#sideslider').stop(true).animate({ 'margin-bottom': -70, 'opacity': '0' }, { queue: false, duration: 300 });
      }
  } else {
      $('#sideslider').stop(true).animate({ 'margin-bottom': 0, 'opacity': '1' }, { queue: false, duration: 300 });
  }
  last = $(this);
});
```

You can change `$("img")` to the actual image elements. I also added the plus that you wanted. However, I did not test this code.

You can also try changing:

```
if (typeof(id) != "undefined" && id !== null){
    oldid = id; 
}
id = event.target.id;
```

To:

```
var id = event.target.id;
if (typeof(id) != "undefined" && id !== null){
    oldid = id; 
}
```